# How to get current timestamp with TimeZone in Java

Tags: java, android, time, timestamp

I want to get `timeStamp` with considering of `TimeZone` in Java in Android,
i tried many ways but still I can't find the solution.

Comment: Get [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) library and use the [`ZonedDateTime`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/ZonedDateTime.html) class. If not that, please edit the question and elaborate on what you mean by *"with considering of TimeZone"*.

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

Use the `ZoneId` & `ZonedDateTime` classes found in the *java.time* package.

```
ZonedDateTime.now()  // Implicitly applies the JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly.

```
ZonedDateTime.now(
    ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) 
)
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that years ago supplanted the terrible legacy classes such as `Timestamp`, `Calendar`, `Date`, `TimeZone`, and `SimpleDateFormat`.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

Capture the current moment as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region, that time zone named above.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

[image: table of legacy and modern classes for date-time handling in Java]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the timestamp with time zone with this method :

```
public static long getTimestampWithGMT() {
    long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    int offset = (TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset() + TimeZone.getDefault().getDSTSavings()) / 1000;

    return timestamp + offset;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Calendar class to get current timestamp. Then you can format this timestamp to display Date, Day, Month, Year, Time etc.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Check out this link:
[Calendar class in java with examples (GeeksForGeeks)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/calendar-class-in-java-with-examples/)

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: I need TimeStamp not a Calendar Object

Answer (score -1):

You can use Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()? It default to device timezone, or if you want to change timeZone you can do something like the following

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

Comment: `getTimeInMillis()` *"returns the current time as UTC milliseconds from the epoch"* (quoting the javadoc), so setting the time zone has no effect, and you might as well just call `System.currentTimeMillis()`.